# jQuery - count number of characters in a input field excluding spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/3e91ropp/

I simple need a way to count the number of characters in an input field excluding spaces.

I need to validate a phone number field to have at least 10 numbers.

I can use the length property but that counts spaces which I don't want to do

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log($('.field').val().length);
  })
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <input class="field" type="text" />
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove the spaces using the [`.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/xqLytwe0/)

```
$('.field').val().replace(/\s+/g, '').length
```

Comment: Use `\s+`, it is better than `\s`

Comment: Yes, performance wise, try to debug the regex `\s` and `\s+` on regex101 and see number of steps required to complete match.